# Simple jquery .css background change image with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background on time with jquery, in my welcome_box div.

```
<div class="welcome_box">
        <p>test</p>
        <small>text</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont need clicks or anything just automatic fadeIn for around 4 images, with a delay of 5 seconds for each image to fadeIn

I cant find a simple code, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which images are you talking about?

Comment: You can't fade background images unless you fade the whole div.  You'll need an image (or element displaying an image) inside the div as well.

Comment: I want the bankground of the div change every 5 seconds, i need simple code for this. i hope you know something that will work easy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269784/jquery-change-background-image-to-several-divs-at-random-intervals
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918986/background-image-change-using-jquery

Comment: Missed part of title referring to background. As Archer said it, you can't apply effect to image background, you should rethink your logic then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. Try this instead

```
<div class="welcome_box">
    <div>
        <p>test</p>
        <small>text</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can achieve this with either CSS or Javascript. For CSS you could use a keyframe animation. You may need to play with the percentages and the timing. I figure 5s x 4 images so I put 20s but I'm not sure if you want to stay longer on each image and make the transition 5s.

```
.welcome_box div
{
animation: myfirst 20s;
-webkit-animation: myfirst 20s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {background: url(image_1) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
9%  {background: url(image_1) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
18%  {background: url(image_2) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
36%  {background: url(image_2) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
45%  {background: url(image_2) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
54% {background: url(image_3) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
63% {background: url(image_3) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
72%  {background: url(image_3) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
81%  {background: url(image_4) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
90% {background: url(image_4) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
99% {background: url(image_4) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background: url(image_1) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
9%  {background: url(image_1) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
18%  {background: url(image_2) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
36%  {background: url(image_2) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
45%  {background: url(image_2) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
54% {background: url(image_3) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
63% {background: url(image_3) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
72%  {background: url(image_3) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
81%  {background: url(image_4) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
90% {background: url(image_4) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:1;}
99% {background: url(image_4) 0 0 no-repeat; opacity:0;}
}
```

The other route using javascript, there are many options but the easiest thing to do is use an existing carousel plugin. This was the first one I found that had automatic fadein http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html

Comment: If you use the carousel example then you need to style your text using  position:absolute; and z-index:1 or greater so it is on a layer above the image. If you use the CSS approach the background image is on a layer below the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var i=0;
setInterval(function(){

 $('.welcome_box').css("background-image","url('images/pic"+i+".jpg')");
 $('.welcome_box').fadeToggle();
 i++;
 if(i==4)
 {
    i=0;
}
},5000);
```

keep the image names like pic1, pic2..etc like that

Comment: code isnt working, trying to figure out

Comment: How does the i value iterate here?

Comment: @user3313356 is this you are looking for?

Comment: its works! but with a fadeIn and out it would be perfect;)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi how can we make it switch with an animation? thanks

Comment: I didnt get your question. Can you explain more.?

Comment: you want fading effect?

Comment: something like that, yes! but then the text fade out to? i just want the image switch with an animation. Also the background of my body shows 0.1ms up when the image switch to the next.. how can we fix that? any idea?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi thats not the way. it toggle's off and 5 sec later it toggles the next image, and repeats it.
Also when the image switch, the background behind the div shows up for some miliseconds. how can we code that away that it doesnt show the background behind the div when it switches?